# Count values of column A observed only with a single distinct value in columns B and/or C

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to summarise a large dataframe in terms of distinct values of one column with respect to whether they are restricted to occuring with single OR multiple distinct values of other column(s). My current approach for doing this is really convoluted, and I'm looking for a pandas pattern for solving these kinds of problems.

Given the following example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'c': ['x', 'x',  'y', 'y',  'z', 'z'],
              's': ['a1', 'a1',  'a1', 'a1',  'a1', 'a2'],
              't': [1, 1,  1, 2,  1, 1]})
```

How may I obtain (and count) the distinct values of column `c`:

1) that are observed only in conjunction with a single value of columns `s` and `t`.
*Desired output: `set('x')` and/or its length: `1`*

2) that are observed only in conjuction with a single value of column `s` but >1 values of column `t`.
*Desired output: `set('y')` and/or its length: `1`*

3) that are observed in conjuction with >1 values of  columns `s` and any number of distinct column `t` values.
*Desired output: `set('z')` and/or its length: `1`*

Edit:
One more q, using the following revised df!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z1', 'z1', 'z2'],
              's': ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a3', 'a4'],
              't': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1],
              'cat': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']})
```

4) observed twice or more, and only in conjunction with a single value of columns `s` and `t`, and also restricted to cat `'a'`
*Desired output: `set('x')` and/or its length: `1`*

Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide an expected output?

Comment: I had specified the desired output, but have now made it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by multiple columns with `keep=False` for all dupes and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = df.duplicated(['c','s','t'], keep=False)
m2 = df.duplicated(['c','s'], keep=False) & ~m1
m3 = df.duplicated(['c','t'], keep=False) & ~m1

a = df.loc[m1, 'c']
print (a)
0    x
1    x
Name: c, dtype: object

b = df.loc[m2, 'c']
print (b)
2    y
3    y
Name: c, dtype: object

c = df.loc[m3, 'c']
print (c)
4    z
5    z
Name: c, dtype: object
```

And then convert columns to sets:

```
out1, out2, out3 = set(a['c']), set(b['c']), set(c['c'])
print (out1)
{'x'}
print (out2)
{'y'}
print (out3)
{'z'}
```

And for lengths:

```
out11, out21, out31 = len(out1), len(out2), len(out3)
print (out11)
print (out21)
print (out31)
1
1
1
```

Another idea is create new column by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat([m1, m2, m3], axis=1, keys=('s&t','s','t'))
print (df1)
     s&t      s      t
0   True  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True  False
3  False   True  False
4  False  False   True
5  False  False   True

df['new'] = df1.dot(df1.columns)
```

And then aggregate with `set`s and function [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df2 = (df.groupby('new')['c']
         .agg([('set', lambda x: set(x)),('count','nunique')])
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
   new  set  count
0    s  {y}      1
1  s&t  {x}      1
2    t  {z}      1
```

Comment: Thank you! : ) Just digesting & applying this to my dataset. I think the second approach is really what I was looking towards, but I see that duplicated() can do most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Bede Constantinides I am offline, on phone only, so better should be create new question, thanks.